# Can the popular opinion in North Korea be determined?

Tags: public-opinion, north-korea

What are the approaches for outsiders to measure/poll public opinion in a closed society like North Korea? In particular, are any figures for the political support of the current government accepted by the scientific community?

(Not my question. Randy Zeitman)

Comment: I think you would be hard pressed to get an honest answer from this

Comment: From reading 2 books by escapees the average North Korean has been so thoroughly brainwashed that they probably genuinely want Kim to have a long life and prosper.  What the "average North Korean" might decide if they had access to free information is an opinion based question until such time as there are reliable polls in that country so is not a suitable question at this time, so I'll vote to close, sorry (without DV).  Welcome aboard, there are certainly other NK questions that can be asked here.

Comment: -4 ... wow... why... Is this a bad question? It's certainly sincere.

Comment: [It is no secret that getting anything meaningful in the way of data out of North Korea can be difficult.](https://beyondparallel.csis.org/considerations-of-risk-and-methodology-for-north-korean-surveys/) The closest answer I've found is: [... that 35 of 36 respondents’ family, friends, or neighbors complain or make jokes about the government in private.](https://beyondparallel.csis.org/no-laughing-matter-north-koreans-discontent-and-daring-jokes/) However, that falls far short of an answer. The question is probably not answerable.

Comment: @RandyZeitman, the question is downvoted and then closed because it does not **allow valid answers** which fit the Stackexchange Q&A format. Your sincerity does not matter. Most people outside North Korea assume that polls within North Korea are given under duress. Polls of defectors are a self-selected sample and hence unscientific. So **we cannot know** what the people in North Korea want. If we cannot know, then the question becomes invalid. (One might have rewritten the question rather than closing it, but a number of people voted to close).

Comment: Ok. I thought it was assumed to be trolling. But it is false that we cannot know what they want. It doesn't have to be a poll. Certainly many there are not brainwashed and want to liberate North Korea ... perhaps reunification with South Korea as per the summit talks resulting in the June 15th 200 North–South Joint Declaration.

Comment: "But it is false that we cannot know what they want." Nope.  There are simply no sources that aggregate the opinions of everyday north Koreans. Everything that comes out of that country must be taken with grains of salt, even the "eyewitness" reports from defectors are often embellished and occasionally completely wrong.

Comment: You mean there are no persons that know the private feelings of their neighbors? No 'underground' community activists? 

"even the "eyewitness" reports from defectors are often embellished and occasionally completely wrong."

Well that's certainly impossible to know if no one's word is truthful.

Comment: @RandyZeitman, underground community activists would be self-selected among people who are willing to question the regime. For instance, defectors are asked if they did listen to foreign radio, or read foreign leaflets, or watch foreign media on memory cards. But what if watching *made* them defect? Honest studies admit that they don't know how many non-defectors watch ROK soap operas. They might have some idea from how loudly the DPRK blames foreign influence, but that is second hand.

Comment: You could read [North Korean House of Cards](https://www.hrnk.org/uploads/pdfs/Gause_NKHOC_FINAL_WEB.pdf) by HRNK, but you would have to be aware that they are very much against the DPRK regime. Or the [UN Commission of Inquiry](https://www.ohchr.org/en/hrbodies/hrc/coidprk/pages/commissioninquiryonhrindprk.aspx). But also read [The Merits of Conducting Surveys Inside North Korea](https://beyondparallel.csis.org/the-merits-of-conducting-surveys-inside-north-korea/) by Beyondparallel.

Comment: Let's keep the discussion of Kim's appearance out of the comments here. If you want to discuss that, feel free to do so [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6619/agora).

Comment: Just want to point out that not all defectors are anti-NK activists.  A not-insignificant amount claim to have been tricked or kidnapped while on work detail China, then smuggled into SK.  I'd take all of this with a huge pile of salt, but it's worth considering; here's a few interviews with some unwilling defectors;
https://youtu.be/ktE_3PrJZO0

Comment: "But what if watching made them defect?"
Ask them.
Why would any human, in any condition, not want to be more free than they are. You speak of brainwash like it's complete and permanent. When the USA seized? controlled? Germany in WWII did the Germans say it was a mistake and wanted Hitler back? Course not, they wanted the freedom to do business, same as Japan.

If the United Nations took over North Korea and suddenly food and medicine showed what would they say ... you're evil?

Comment: @RandyZeitman, the point is that we **cannot know the numbers.** The only people we can ask are the defectors. I expect that a significant number of people left in the DPRK would welcome regime change, just as a significant number would oppose it. And quite a lot will be afraid that *any* short-term disruption of supply chains will kill them, whatever the long-term benefits might be.

Comment: @Ryan_L It would be interesting to corelate the number of defectors who claim to have been tricked or kidnapped with the number of defectors who have family members at risk still in the NK.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the approaches for outsiders to measure/poll public opinion
> in a closed society like North Korea?

Interview defectors, monitor public statements of the government and publicly known economic activity, interview what the small volume of officially permitted tourists and visitors regarding what they have seen, rely in secret informants (i.e. spies) in North Korea (relationships that are hard to maintain and few in number), and monitor telecommunications and remote viewing (e.g. from satellites and viewing from across the border).

None of these methods are terribly precise or accurate. All have huge blind spots.

> In particular, are any figures for the political support of the
> current government accepted by the scientific community?

No.

Comment: There are no spys in NK? From any country?
What does SK say that NK wants?

Comment: @RandyZeitman There are spies in NK. Not many, none with comprehensive knowledge, and limited in their ability to get information out. The aggregate quality of the information that SK and other agencies are getting out of NK is appalling thin even on very, very basic issue. At best you get anecdotal information and information on behavior at the very top. But the question is asking about the consensus re sentiment of the general public & political support, something Gallup, etc. do regularly in most of the world, but that doesn't exist in NK. Maybe the concept doesn't even make sense in NK.

Comment: @RandyZeitman Certainly, none of the available sources are providing "figures" for the political support of the current government let alone "figures" accepted by the scientific community.

Comment: @RandyZeitman If those spies in North Korea would run around with clipboards asking random people about their opinion on the government, then there wouldn't be spies in North Korea for long.

Comment: @Philipp  How do countries outside North Korea gather intelligence about NK? If you accept that info is accurate then why wouldn't information about the desires of the people at large be accurate?

Comment: @RandyZeitman Espionage and science are not the same thing. In espionage, you usually have to accept that your information might not be reliable and make decisions based on best guesses. In science, the only use for unreliable information is to form a hypothesis which should not be used for decision-making until it was confirmed or falsified by more reliable data.

Comment: @Philipp I've not mentioned science. Why did you introduce that comparison?

Comment: @RandyZeitman The words "accepted by the scientific community" appear right in the question. What the scientific community accepts is "science".

Comment: @ohwilleke Thank you. It's not my question and the question is absurd for exactly the reason you say. Close it or take my name off it.